# Heroku Discord Bot is offline - Python

Tags: python, json, heroku, deployment, discord.py

I successfully deployed my discord.py code on Heroku using GitHub desktop but the bot doesn't , I checked the log but no activity of my @client.event "Bot is online" what I'm doing wrong?

[github files](https://github.com/richcipriano/billionaireboysclub)

**Heroku log:**

```
2020-08-30T22:14:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-08-30T22:16:22.693312+00:00 app[api]: Set token config vars by user mallkz@hotmail.com
2020-08-30T22:16:22.693312+00:00 app[api]: Release v21 created by user mallkz@hotmail.com
```

**EDIT:**

I activate the Free Dynos and recieved

```
2020-08-30T22:49:59.122979+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-30T22:50:01.980358+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `: python economia.py`
2020-08-30T22:50:02.627389+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-08-30T22:50:03.612552+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-08-30T22:50:03.645671+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: `heroku --logs` and check the logs

Comment: How about you show some your python code. The GitHub link is not working.